# Firefox can't update to the latest version

Tags: firefox

Firefox does not automatically update to the latest version:

[image]

When I click on download Firefox it directs to me to the usual download page. How do I update firefox?

Comment: To use a workaround until Canonical releases 66.0.4, get your extensions working again by enabling "studies": https://twitter.com/mozamo/status/1124731439809830912 You'll get a hot-fix; you can disable when the new release comes out. If you want to get it quickly, go to `about:config`, and search for `app.normandy.run_interval_seconds` - set value to `10`. When the study is installed/running, re-set this value to default `21600`. To check the hot-fix is installed, visit `about:studies`. It looks [like this](https://i.imgur.com/Dfzs3eJ.png). Hope that helps.

Comment: @Dɑvïd Your solutions works fine on Ubuntu 18.04, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update Firefox over the package manager
Open the Terminal while pressing Ctrl+Alt+T
Enter:

```
sudo apt update
```

and then do

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

You may be asked for your password.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now on Mozilla Firefox 66.0.3 but I need 66.0.4 because my add-ons don't work anymore.

Comment: The addon problem was a huge bug in firefox, the hotfix is new, give canonical some time to update firefox to 66.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu firefox is usually behind firefox package releases. What you can do is to manually install latest firefox even if ubuntu hasn't release a tested firefox package.
Download latest desktop mozilla from

[Firefox for Linux](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/linux/)

Then simply delete firefox at **/opt/firefox** (or check where the firefox is installed using **whereis firefox**) and replace the content of downloaded package **firefox** to **/opt/**

If you get error in starting the latest firefox you can start it in safe mode by

```
firefox -safe-mode
```

and refresh. All your bookmarks etc will be saved or go here to see what refreshing does

[refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)

once refresh completes try again starting firefox. Once started check the about in **Help > About Firefox**, and it should match with the latest version of firefox.

I have updated firefox in the same way on Ubuntu20.04.